# How to give quick response to httpRequest?

Tags: asp.net

I receive httpRequest which raises long business logic (about 1 sec). I must give answer to httpSender during 0.2 sec, otherwise I receive the second httpRequest.

Now I encountered with next issue: I give httpResponse right after receiving httpRequest, but Response.End() stop working all the rest. So, to achieve this: both give quick response and process request?

I see only creating thread and processing request in other thread, but I'm afraid that Response.End() will stop a thread too.

Comment: Is there a result of that business logic that will need to be returned? If so, how do you plan to do that if the response is ended?

Comment: No, I return always the same result to a sender. So business logic is not related with http response

Answer (score 0):

You should handle you business logic async from your http call handling. Start a new thread which handles the bl method and continue with sending the response. Your thread will not be stopped if you start it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right, you can send only one response for one request and doing this asynchronously won't help you because you can't hold the request until background thread finishes it. The ideal way to solve this is to break your api(server methods) in small parts and optimize your logic so it can response in expected time.
And if you are computing large data sets than Its recommended to use windows-service(or some other background mechanism) for computation and store computed data in database.

Answer (score 0):

Start the request sending via [Response.Flush()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush.aspx) as soon as possible, before the long-running task is started. That will send the headers to the client immediately. Reminder: You won't be able to alter the HTTP headers after that call.

Comment: You mean, that I can write next code  Response.Flush();  /* my logic */ Response.Write("ok"); Response.End();  ?